# Ruby on Rails has_secure_password validation gets errors on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have working on a Ruby on Rails application and have a problem. I've user model in my domain and it has a `has_secure_password` field like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true
    validates :password, length: { in: 6..20, message: 'Password shoul be minimum 6 characters'}
end
```

And I save the user object with this function:

```
def self.create_with_params(email,name,password)
    user = User.new()
    user.provider= :mail
    user.name=name
    user.email=email
    user.password=password
    user.activate_status=false

    user.save(validate: true);

    return user;
end
```

That's ok too.

But when I want to update a field in my user model. I get validation error for `password` field.

```
@user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) # this record has a valid password_digest field in database.
@user.name = 'John'
@user.save

puts @user.errors.full_messages
```

It prints:

> "Password shoul be minimum 6 characters".

Note: I have `password_digest` field in my users table.

I think when I query `users` table `password_digest` field couldn't be filled in to `password` field on model.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If password is a virtual field you should only validate it when you need to.

Answer (score 3):

> I think when I query Users table password_digest field couldn't be
>   filled in to password field on model.

Correct, the password is not stored, so when you query `User` you don't get the `password` field, yet your model asks for it every time with:

```
validates :password, presence: true
```

So, you will need to provide `password` before saving `@user` to make it work, but i guess that is not what you want, so just remove that validation from your model,

You won't need to validate `password` every time, just upon creating, and that validation is done with `has_secure_password`.

Also, for the same reason, you will need to update `length` validation to:

```
validates :password, length: { in: 6..20, message: 'Password shoul be minimum 6 characters'}, allow_nil: true
```